# Appending temporary lists from loop ends up with multiple copies of the same list

Tags: python

I am trying to practice to make a method.

```
s = '132'
lis = list(s)
result = []
lisc = lis[:]

for item in lis:
    for i in range(1,len(lis)):

        lisc.remove(item)
        lisc.insert(i,item)
        print("lis : ", lisc)
        result.append(lisc)

print(result)
```

The result is :

```
lis :  ['3', '1', '2']
lis :  ['3', '2', '1']
lis :  ['2', '3', '1']
lis :  ['2', '1', '3']
lis :  ['1', '2', '3']
lis :  ['1', '3', '2']
[['1', '3', '2'], ['1', '3', '2'], ['1', '3', '2'], ['1', '3', '2'], ['1', '3', '2'], ['1', '3', '2']]
```

I don't get why the result is appending the original lisc instead of the modified lisc in the loop.

I tried result.append(lisc[:]) and it works.

```
for item in lis:
    for i in range(1,len(lis)):

        lisc.remove(item)
        lisc.insert(i,item)
        print("lis : ", lisc)
        result.append(lisc[:])

print(result)
```

Can anyone answer my question?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You keep modifying the same list.

Comment: It's because `result.append(lisc)` does not create a new copy of `lisc`. It just add a reference to the same list object that `lisc` points to. Hence, all the elements in `result` are pointing to the same list object. When you use `lisc[:]`, you are actually adding the content of the list to `result`, therefore making a complete copy of them.

Comment: Check this out: In your 1st version, after your `for` loop, but before you print, add this line `lisc[:] = ['hi', 'there']`.

Answer (score 0):

In the first version of your code, you append the same list that it's being updated at every iteration. In the end, all the `lisc` you appended will be a reference to the same list

In the second version, you append a new copy of the modified list. Those copies are all different object